# FusedLocationApi delivers null

Tags: android, geolocation

I am using this code

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
```

to get the last Location of the user. If I enable the location services in Android, it works fine, but if I disable them, the LocationApi delivers null. The Google Documantation says, the Api delivers normaly an Object, and just in some rare cases, the Object can be null. But it is null, as soon as the User disables the Location Service in Android. This is more the standard than the rare case. I thought it would at least give me the last known location which was saved anywhere, or a location with really low precission. 
Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to get the location anytime I need it  (the precission is not important, as long as it is not far away)? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its expected read the docs. When there is no last location available it will return null.

Comment: That is, why i thought they store the location, and if there is no current location service available, they it delivers this stored one

Comment: Did you figure it out after all? I totally agree with you